# how to call a function after the termination of another function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have 3 functions and I would like to call one after the other

```
openTryFunction(){
    // function one
    this.functionOne();
    // after function one
    this.functionTwo();
    // after function two
    this.functionTree(); }
```

Comment: And what issue are you having in doing that? It should be fine...

Comment: one depends on the outcome of the other

Comment: Yep, still don't see an issue here unless the functions are asynchronous.

Comment: @user184994 `functionOne()` and `functionTwo()` may be asynchronous.

Comment: in typescript is asynchronous, so the next function depends on the previous

Comment: Can you please add the code for the three functions? Without it, it's impossible to give an accurate answer

Answer (score 23):

So you have three functions `functionOne`, `functionTwo`, and `functionThree`. There can be multiple PnCs of whether any of these functions is synchronous or asynchronous.

Let's generalize these scenarios into two main categories:

1. **All are synchronous**: If this is the case, your code is going to run one after the other(synchronously).
2. **If any of the function is async**: If this is the case, then the function that is async in nature should let the function that is supposed to be called after that, to know that it has terminated. In this case, you can either return a Promise/Observable from that async function. Or you can pass it a callback function that will get called after the async function finishes execution.

Two examples of this would be:

1. Let's say all these functions are async in nature and all these functions return an Observable:

Then you should be writing it like:

```
openTryFunction() {
  this.functionOne()
    .subscribe(
      () => this.functionTwo()
              .subscribe(() => this.functionThree()
                                 .subscribe(() => console.log('Function three terminated')))
    );
}
```

2. If your `functionOne` and `functionTwo` returns a promise, then,:

```js
openTryFunction() {
  this.functionOne().then(() => {
    this.functionTwo().then(() => this.functionThree());
  });
}
```

**Update:**

You can also use `async` and `await` for a cleaner code. Here's a simple yet concrete example for the same:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular';
  users;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAllData();
  }

  getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .toPromise();
  }

  getUserPosts(userId) {
    return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${userId}`)
      .toPromise();
  }

  getPostComments(postId) {
    return this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=${postId}`)
      .toPromise();
  }

  async getAllData() {
    const users = await this.getUsers();
    const posts = await this.getUserPosts(users[0].id);
    const comments = await this.getPostComments(posts[0].id);

    console.log(users);
    console.log(posts);
    console.log(comments);
  }

}
```

Here's a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-async-await-eg) for the same.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Small suggestion: with this code you won't know when `functionTree` has completed

Comment: For my case, functionOne and functionTwo are async and return promise. functionThree is a simple synchronous method. Not sure how to apply it?

Answer (score 4):

You can use Promise:

```
functionOne(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve((() => {
        // code here
        return 'from first'; // return whatever you want not neccessory
    })());
}

functionTwo(): Promise<any> {
    return Promise.resolve((() => {
        // code here
        return 'from second'; // return whatever you want not neccessory
    })());
}

functionThree() {
    // code here
}



this.functionOne().then(data1 => {
    console.log(data1);
    this.functionTwo().then(data2 => {
        console.log(data2);
        this.functionThree();
    });
});
```

Comment: @Faisal Hmm, It is resolving an anonymous function that is returning something.

Comment: You can resolve the data e.g. **`resolve('from second');`**

Answer (score 4):

If your functions are synchronous what you are doing is fine. If they are asynchronous and they return promises then you can string them together as so:

```
fOne()
  .then(() => {
    fTwo()
 } ).then(() => {
  fThree()
});
```

Alternatively you can use an async await.

```
async function tasks() {
  await fOne();
 await fTwo();
 await fThree();
}
```

Be sure to us try catch to handle exceptions.

If your functions return observables then concatMap is your friend.

```
fOne()
    .concatMap(() => fTwo())
    .concatMap(() => fThree());
```

Given your last function Does not return a promise you can omit await on the last call assuming you use async await.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this example where each function returns an `Observable` and the sequence of execution is controlled by a `concat` function.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular';
  values = [];

  first(): Observable<string> {
    return of('first');
  }

  second(): Observable<string> {
    return of('second');
  }

  afterSecond(): Observable<string> {
    return of('secondish');
  }

  third(): Observable<string> {
    return of('third');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let sequence = concat([
      this.first, 
      this.second, 
      this.afterSecond, 
      this.third]);

    sequence.subscribe(currentFunction => {
      currentFunction().subscribe(value => {
        this.values.push(value);
      })
    });
  }

}
```

I like the `concat` function as it build an `Observable` of the functions we add to the list.

Note that this call `sequence.subscribe(currentFunction` each value in `currentFunction` will be a function, and in order to have the actual value of it, as it is an `Observable` you need to subscribe to it.

Please see the full example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-functions-in-sequence?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

If the functions return an observable, then simply call the next function in **`subscribe`**. Otherwise, return a promise from each function. Then you can chain the called functions.

```
functionOne() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        //
        // Your function implementation
        //
        // Resolve the promise at the end
        resolve(); 
    });
}

functionTwo() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        //
        // Your function implementation
        //
        // Resolve the promise at the end
        resolve(); 
    });
}

functionThree() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        //
        // Your function implementation
        //
        // Resolve the promise at the end
        resolve(); 
    });
}


openTryFunction(){
    // function one
    this.functionOne().then(() => {
        // after function one
        this.functionTwo().then(() => {
            // after function two
            this.functionTree(); 
        });        
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
openTryFunction(){
this.functionOne().then(()=>{this.functionTwo().then(() => {this.functionTree()})})}
```

function 3 will run when 2 is done and 2 will run when 1 is done.

Comment: Only if the first and the second function returns promise.