# Angular - how to chain multiple calls

Tags: angular

In my angular 7 application, I need to chain multiple HTTP Get call and for any call I need to wait for the call before to be completed also if I don't need to use directly the response in the next call.

I don't want to use subscribe inside a subscribe and so on because the code is very bad.

So for example, if I have 4 functions what is the best practice to achieve it?

Comment: you can use async/await

Comment: If possible I want to avoid promise

Comment: You are looking for RxJS `switchMap` if you want to use the result form the first request in the second request and so on. Use `combineLatest` or `forkJoin` if you simply want to await all requests to finish.

Comment: you can use forkJoin  from 'rxjs';  // RxJS 6 syntax

Comment: Check if [how to call a function after the termination of another function in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115904/how-to-call-a-function-after-the-termination-of-another-function-in-angular) helps

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if you need something different

Answer (score 4):

Try `forkJoin`:

```
linkContractToDepartment(data): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(
            '/something/link-contract',
            data
        );
}

calls = [];
calls.push(this.linkContractToDepartment(1));
calls.push(this.linkContractToDepartment(2));


forkJoin(calls).subscribe(response_list=> { console.log(response_list) })
```

Comment: From the question to me it is unclear if he wants to await multiple requests or if he wants to use the result from the first call in the second call. For the second case, switchMap should be used.

Comment: @CanK. : he has said `I don't need to use directly the response in the next call`. so there is no dependency of responses, so we can call all at once

Comment: @ShashankVivek I think it's pretty clear that switchmap needs to be used... "I need to wait for the call before to be completed, **ALSO** if I don't need to use directly the response in the next call."

Comment: I guess it would have been more clear if OP had written `even if I don't need to use...` But English isn't everyone's native or second language :)

Comment: Sometimes I need to use the response of the precedent call but often I don't need it, I also need all the response in the last subscribe so I can elaborate all

Answer (score 1):

Like other said, Angular works perfectly with [RxJS](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api). But the official doc is a bit confuse. Try to find real world example with angular AND RXJS. Example : https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293

[Learn rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) is another nice ressource for RxJS

To resume:

- To avoid subscribe of subscribe use **Observable**.
- If multiple async call are independent use **forkJoin**
- If an async call need previous async query use **mergeMap**
- if async call need multiple async query use **combineLatest**